# In Swift, How to have a json request automatically cancel itself if the data returned is of a different format?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm running into this problem where JSON data downloaded from a site is of a different format compared to other data received from the same site. This problem is causing the app to freeze.  For example 98% percent of the data received from the site looks like this:

```
{
id: 27673,
title: "Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt",
alternate_titles: [ ],
status: "",
type: "online",
container_show: 0,
first_aired: "2015-02-17",
network: ""
}
```

but for some strange reason some of the JSON data is formatted like this:

```
{
id: 35107,
title: "Jessica Jones",
alternate_titles: [ ],
status: "",
type: "online",
container_show: 0,
first_aired: false,
network: ""
}
```

The value for "first_aired" is a string for the first JSON data but a Bool for the second. Is there to make the JSON data automatically cancel the request if the format of the JSON data changes and go back to the original view it was on before the request was made? Or even better just skip over the value that is different than the original format but still retrieve the rest of the data?

Comment: When you get the JSON back, why don't you just inspect the type of `first_aired`? If it's a bool, do you navigation flow to go back. If it's a string, you know it's valid

Comment: You could use something like `let aired = first_aired as? String ?? "Unavailable"`. Why would you not display the rest of the data? Does it really need to be skipped?

Comment: I'm still new to working with JSON data.  I usually do something like this with the data: let firstAired = jsonResult["first_aired"] as? String,
How can I inspect it first?

Comment: @Caleb -I just tried your approach. I get the error " Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: @Caleb - Nevermind, I had to get rid of the guard else statement first.

Answer (score 0):

Caleb's method worked.  I removed the optional binding from all the JSON data and instead have it set up like this:

```
let firstAired = jsonResult["first_aired"] as? String ?? "N/A"
```

It worked like a charm.  The app doesn't freeze anymore and when the JSON data is of a different format it reads "N/A" instead.